# How to use craigslist api for searching on HTML page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple html page which I'm using to search using craigslist api. 
How should I display the results from that query back to HTML page?

This is the code to query the craigslist.

```
var
  craigslist = require('node-craigslist'),
  client = new craigslist.Client({
    city : 'seattle'
  });

client
  .search('xbox one')
  .then((listings) => {
    // play with listings here...
    listings.forEach((listing) => console.log(listing));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Any idea how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

use expressjs you can query back that response into html page for example you create your server first in node js first we install expressjs like this:

```
npm install express body-parser --save
```

first create an index.html that can receive our table like this:

```
<script 

    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>.zui-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}</style>
<div ng-app="panda">
    <div ng-controller="main">
<h2>Craiglist</h2>        
<form ng-submit="searching()">
<input ng-model="search" type="text"/>    
</form>
<table class="zui-table">
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="(key,value) in list[0]">{{key}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="koi in list">
            <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in koi">{{value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("panda", []);

app.controller("main", function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.list=[]
    $scope.searching=function(text){
        $http.post("/craiglist",{search:$scope.search}).then(data=>{
            console.log(data.data)
            $scope.list=data.data
        })
    }
});

</script>
```

after that create a nodejs server lets say the name is server.js file like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
app.get('/',async (req, res) => {
await res.sendFile(__dirname'/index.html')
})

 app.post('/craiglist',bodyParser.json(),async (req, res) => {
 var  craigslist = require('node-craigslist'),
  client = new craigslist.Client({
    city : 'seattle'
  });

const listing=await client.search(req.body.search)
await res.send(listing)
})
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

and dont forget this code using the latest nodejs so install latest nodejs first in order to use async/await function

Comment: I'm trying to implement a search box in HTML page which would display results using craigslist api. How would I include the results in my html page using above?

Comment: if you use search box you can try create an html that request to for example app.get('/listing') in nodejs server than in your html just append that listing into some html element

Comment: Can you explain it in little more detail? I'm not getting as to how would I put it in the html. Can you give an example?

Comment: do you know about rest api?or ajax?

Comment: i edit my answer please look at it and ask me if you have any question

Comment: Hi Rino, Thanks a lot for your input. I've followed all your directions and have installed required components but when I open index.html and search for anything I do not get back any results. Is there anything else I'd have to do to get the results?

Comment: can you show me the console output in your browser?

Comment: I'm not getting any output. After typing something in the text box nothing happens. I don't get any result. Page stays the same. I don't know how to share that with you here. Also, there is no search button in index.html to search for keywords. On my http server in terminal I'm getting "GET /" Error (404): "Not found"

Comment: I'm getting following errors in my console: angular.js:12587 Failed to load file:///craiglist: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12587
angular.js:14525 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/craiglist","data":{"search":"tickets"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":""}

Comment: there is no need for search button just enter it.is there any error in the node server?

Comment: I'm getting following errors: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:8080/craiglist Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
angular.js:14525 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"","status":405,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/craiglist","data":{"search":"tickets"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Method Not Allowed"}

Comment: I'm able to load the index.html page on localhost but am not getting any results. Following errors on server: [Fri Nov 24 2017 22:27:52 GMT-0800 (PST)] "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found"
[Fri Nov 24 2017 22:27:57 GMT-0800 (PST)] "POST /craiglist" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
[Fri Nov 24 2017 22:27:57 GMT-0800 (PST)] "POST /craiglist" Error (404): "Not found"

Comment: have you install node-craigslist?

Comment: Yes I have installed node-craigslist

Comment: $http.post("/craiglist",{search:$scope.search}).then(data=>{ app.post('/craiglist',bodyParser.json(),async (req, res) => {  I think the error is because of the above two lines. It is not able to recognise /craiglist

Comment: install cors with npm install cors --save then add var cors=require(''cors");app.use(cors()) below require("body-parser")

Comment: Installed above components. Still no result. Are you getting output in your system?

Comment: yes look at this link https://distribusi-spiritbro.c9users.io/ try to search something than click enter

Comment: Yes it works for you. I have no idea why it's throwing errors for me :( Have you made any changes to the above code?

Comment: nope its the same do you want the entire file that i have here i will share it on github?

Comment: Yeah Rino!! That would surely help me if you could do that. Thanks a ton

Comment: Hi Rino! Thanks for sharing your code. But for some reason it still does not work on my system. I've tried doing the same thing on other system too still no results. Can you please reactivate your above link on which it was working? I'd really appreciate it